# My Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise edition CodeLens does not display

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Toggle the CodeLens feature off and then on again.

But CodeLens not display on method.

Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise edition working well, in same PC.

Go into Tools -> Options... -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> CodeLens.

Uncheck "Enable CodeLens" option and click OK.

Go back into Tools -> Options... -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> CodeLens.
Check the "Enable CodeLens" option and click OK.

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I've managed to solve the issue for now.
I've deleted the `.suo` file under hidden folder `.vs`, which lives in solution folder. Just navigate inside this `.vs` folder and find the `v15` subfolder. Inside it, it will be a `.suo` file. Delete it and restart VS 2017.
Hope it works for you!

Comment: sadly this doesn't work for me on VS 2017 Enterprise 15.5.6

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution mentioned here, it did not work. 
So I just went ahead n reset the vs settings which did the trick.

**Tools>Import and Export settings>Reset all settings** (I did not save previous settings)